# Determining The Sparsity or Density of a Chroma Vector

Tags: matlab, audio, sparsity

I have a range of songs where I have took an 'unfolded' chromagram computed from a series of short-term windows.  Specifically, for one song, I have one vector which contains the amplitudes of the chroma's, and a second vector which contains the corresponding MIDI notes.  For now, I can plot a histogram of the amplitudes w.r.t the MIDI notes that gives me a visual idea of the range of notes used.

Here are two songs graphed:

[image: graphs]

As we can see, the 'classical' example is in my opinion more sparse than its neighbouring graph.  I've been trying to figure out a way as to how to measure for something like this, since I need to fold such a feature vector into 1 useful statistic.

Comment: Probably you can use sparsity as a useful statistic. The sparsity of a vector is the number of non-zero components of the vector. It is denoted mathematically using $L_0$-norm which is popular in sparse representation and in compressed sensing. For example, if $x=[1 0 0 -1 2.3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]$, which of length $N=14$, its sparsity is, that is,  $L_0$-norm is  $\|x \|_0=4$. It is a 4-sparse vector.

Comment: Sorry there some notation error in the above comment. The $$x=\left[1~0~ ~0~-1~2.3~0~0~0~0~1~0~0~0~0~\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it this and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering a similar problem as well and I found Gini index as one of the solution: [Gini Index as Sparsity Measure for Signal Reconstruction from Compressive Samples](http://www.eng.nus.edu.sg/eleashra/TJSTSP_Gini.pdf). Please have a look at the definition in page 3. It is normalized in the range from 0 to 1 as the least sparse or the most sparse the vector is, respectively.

The code below is an implementation in Python, though I am not sure about returning 0 if the input is a zero vector:

```
def gini(v):
    v = np.array(v)
    sort_v = sort(abs(v))
    norm_v = sum(sort_v)
    if norm_v==0:
        return(0)
    else:
        sig = 0 
        for k in arange(len(sort_v))+1:
            sig+=(sort_v[k-1]/(norm_v))*((len(sort_v)-k+0.5)/len(sort_v))
        return(1-2*sig)
```

Answer (score 1):

In [Comparing Measures of Sparsity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2009.2027527), 2009, IEEE Trans. Information Theory, an axiomatic characterization of sparsity for random sources, and a comparison of different measures is provided. Two measures emerged (in my reading): the [Gini index or coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient), as proposed above, and the $\ell_1/\ell_2$ norm ratio, illustrated below.

[image]

It stems from a [standard norm inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218046/relations-between-p-norms) between $\ell_1$ and  $\ell_2$ ($\ell_2 \le \ell_1 \le \sqrt{n}\ell_2$, with $n$ the length of the signal,  through Cauchy-Schwarz or Hölder inequality), that saturates on both ends for:

- the nonzero-constant signal,
- the all-zero-but-one signal,

and being scale-invariant, zero-homogeneous (as the Gini index or the $\ell_0$ counting index).

While the Gini index seems the more natural, the second one can  be  used more easily in subsequent processing, for instance restoration, as it provides a computable non-convex penalty. For a recent paper with an historical account for the norm ratio: [Euclid in a Taxicab: Sparse Blind Deconvolution with Smoothed $\ell _1/\ell _2$ Regularization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/LSP.2014.2362861), 2015, IEEE Signal Processing Letters.

A `Matlab` code is given below:

```
function mos_l1_l2 = MoS_Hoyer_ratio_l1_l2(data)

if isequal(data,0)
  mos_l1_l2 = 0;
else
  mos_l1_l2 = sum(abs(data))./sqrt(sum((data).^2));
end
```